# Java Array Synchronization (Visibility)

Tags: java, arrays, synchronization

I am trying to understand exactly how element visibility works on arrays in java.

Given the class:

```
class IntList {

    private final int[] array;

    public IntList(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public int[] readElements() {
        return Arrays.copyof(this.array, this.array.length);
    }

}
```

and the following method body for creating an instance:

```
int[] array = new int[length];
fillArrayWithRandomData(array); // puts data into the array from arbitrary source
return new IntList(array);
```

I am wondering if the elements in the `IntList` are guaranteed to be visible by other threads that obtain a reference to the returned `IntList`?

I am sure that the REFERENCE to the array will be visible because it is final but I cannot seem to find a guarantee that the elements in the array will be visible as well.

Note: The `IntList` class has no methods that allow the modification of the array and the array reference is not published to any other object, I am only wondering about visibility after construction.

**Edit:** Sorry, my class is not called `String` in my actual implementation.  I changed the class name to `IntList` because there seems to be too much confusion.

**Edit:** 
The final answer I'll put here is Yes, the elements are visible.
@MikeClark found the JLS answer:
JLS § 17.5 "The usage model for final fields is a simple one: Set the final fields for an object in that object's constructor; and do not write a reference to the object being constructed in a place where another thread can see it before the object's constructor is finished. If this is followed, then when the object is seen by another thread, that thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that object's final fields. It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are."

Thanks again!

Comment: please don't call your classes as built-in classes. String clashes with java.lang.String - and may cause you no end of problems.

Comment: field visibility and threads are orthogonal notions. Visibility is only related to where your code is, where the field is, and what are the modifiers, not to which thread executes the code

Comment: what package are you running that from?

Comment: @SamuelRossille "visibility" is a term often used when discussing the [Java] memory model, which is a topic highly relevant to multithreading.  See, for example, this discussion of the Java Memory Model leading up to the revised Java 5 JMM: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/. "One of the key concepts needed to understand the JMM is that of visibility -- how do you know that if thread A executes someVariable = 3, other threads will see the value 3 written there by thread A?"

Comment: @SamuelRossille Unless you're talking about visibility of stack variables (which he sort of is) and reference publishing (also sort of related), in which case it's definitely applicable to threads.

Comment: Also, thank you for changing the name of your class. It confuses all the people with ~100 rep that don't read the questions into thinking you mean `java.util.String`, and it just makes answering these questions a nightmare. +1

Comment: @MikeClark - "Visibility" is an overloaded term. When talking about the Java _language_ (as opposed to the Java memory model) it usually refers to the [_access modifiers_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) (`public`, `private`, etc.)--as in _"Let's look at a collection of classes and see how access levels affect visibility."_

Comment: @TedHopp - the term "visibility" is also used heavily when referring to changes made across threads.  see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/memory.html

Comment: @MikeClark - you should make your comment an answer since none of the current answers gets it quite right.

Comment: @MikeClark and Brian I didn't know that meaning of visibility. Ignorance caused my mistake. Tx for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are populating the array in the constructor then yes, any call to `new String(int[] array)` will have the array initialized by the time it returns. The `final` keyword will also guarantee that the most recent changes to the `array` parameter at the time of assignment will be visible.

Comment: there is no such constructor String(int[])

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev - There is in OP's class. (It's not `java.lang.String`.)

Comment: Yes, I understand that if i populated the array in the constructor it will be visible to other threads but the point was that I am populating the array before the constructor and simply setting the rerference in the constructor.

Comment: Exactly, so by the time the reference is set in the constructor the array is already populated, it's the same concept exactly.

Comment: And since you have it marked final you can guarantee that the reference will never change (individual array elements can be modified later of course)

Comment: Thanks!  This answers my question exactly.

Comment: @nikdeapen - it may answer your question, but it doesn't explain "why" (i.e. the special memory effects that the "final" modifier has).

Comment: AFAIK, `final` doesn't have any impact on OP's question. The reference is set before the new object is returned regardless, right?

Comment: Yes, my may have been a bit confusing but all I wanted to know was if the elements inside the array would be visible to other threads after the construction of class.

Comment: JLS § 17.5 "The usage model for final fields is a simple one: Set the final fields for an object in that object's constructor; and do not write a reference to the object being constructed in a place where another thread can see it before the object's constructor is finished. If this is followed, then when the object is seen by another thread, that thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that object's final fields.  **It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are**."

Comment: I was also assuming the elements in the array did not change by any means after the construction of the class.

Comment: So as a practical example of this, if the OP had some other thread possibly modifying the array instance that was passed in, the `final` keyword will provide an added benefit that the very latest values of that array will be visible. Makes sense. That doesn't seem to be the case for the example OP presented here though.

Comment: @jtahlborn how is that not what I said in the comment right before yours? If thread X modifies `array` before the constructor is called, the `final` keyword ensures that those changes are visible when the assignment is made. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found this is very helpful http://jeremymanson.blogspot.ch/2009/06/volatile-arrays-in-java.html
So basically everything happens before volatile read is guaranteed to be  seen by other threads. So there is some hack to make it happen.
In addtion, jaa provide native AtomicReference/Long/Integer/...Array support. which will make sure update is visible to other threads.

Answer (score -2):

A lot of distinct concepts seem to be mixed up in your question.

- visibility and `final` have nothing to do with one another
- visibility and threads have nothing to do with one another
- a `private` variable is not visible outside the class to any other code, regardless of whether it is final
- a `final` array can still have its elements changed. It is only the reference to the array itself that is `final`.

When you construct your `IntList` object (and by the way, thanks for changing the name) like this:

```
public IntList(int[] array) {
    this.array = array;
}
```

the internal `this.array` field references the same array object that was passed to the constructor. The array could still be modified from outside the `String` class:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
IntList list = new IntList(array);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.readElements()); // prints [1, 2, 3]
array[1] = 0;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.readElements()); // prints [1, 0, 3]
```

You can insulate your class from this by making a copy of the array in the constructor:

```
public IntList(int[] array) {
    this.array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
}
```

Comment: But `final` *does* have to do with memory visibility.  See e.g. http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#finalRight Also the JLS § 17.5 "final fields also allow programmers to implement thread-safe immutable objects without synchronization. A thread-safe immutable object is seen as immutable by all threads, even if a data race is used to pass references to the immutable object between threads."  The OP is clearly talking about memory visibility, not lexical visibility (scoping).

Comment: @MikeClark Of course, not to be misleading, a final array is not immutable. The only way to ensure immutability of an array is to use scoped visibility so that the public access can be made to return copies.

Comment: @Brian A good point.  A Java array is mutable, and so care must be taken.  However, `final` can be used to make guarantees about the visibility of the contents of an array, if used with careful attention to the constraints of the JLS: "[Another thread] will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are."

Comment: @MikeClark - OP did not say "memory visibility"; it seems to me to be a question about whether array elements can be changed once the object is constructed. The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) defines "visible" in terms of scoping: "A declaration d is said to be _visible at point p in a program_ if the scope of d includes p, and d is not shadowed by any other declaration at p." This has nothing to do with the memory model.

Comment: @TedHopp He did not say "memory visibility", but he clearly implied it.  His statement "I am wondering if the elements in the IntList are guaranteed to be visible by other threads".  This *exactly* the kind of question the Java Memory Model sets out to answer.  I agree "visibility" is an overloaded term, and without any other contextual clues I would assume the term "visibility" refers to scoping.  But his mention of threading and specifically data visibility to other threads put his question firmly in the arena of *memory* visibility, not scoping.